# Pods migration from one node to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, aws-auto-scaling

I currently have an unmanaged node group consisting of 2 worker nodes. Node1 has pods running and has enough CPU capacity to run node2's pods. Is there a way in AWS to automatically migrate pods from node2 to node1 and scale down node2? So whenever a worker node has sufficient CPU capacity, it will be filled and the other node will be scaled down to optimize the costs of an unnecessary node?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to migrate the pod. just cordon the node the workload from that node gets automatically shifted to other available node.